# div height does not include childrens

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my parent div height.

It's not containing children in it.

JSBIN: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pavune/2/edit)

Basic of problem is:

I have code like this:

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <div class="left">
     --SOME STUFF--
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    --SOME STUFF--
  </div>
</div>
```

And `.itemsContainer` calculated height does not contains height of children.

Look at JSBin for more code.

Could you please give me a hint, how can i fix that?

Comment: I'm assuming there is some CSS involved; please include it in your question (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because `floats` are not being cleared.

**Solution1:**

Clear floats.

HTML:

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="left">
        --SOME STUFF--
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        --SOME STUFF--
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

[**See DEMO.**](http://jsbin.com/surujamo/1/edit)

**Solution2:**

Add following:

```
.itemsContainer{overflow:hidden;}
```

[**See DEMO.**](http://jsbin.com/zufoveza/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your float element after the child div complete like below.

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
<div class="left">
 --SOME STUFF--
</div>
<div class="right">
 --SOME STUFF--
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[**Updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/weyojako/1)